# How to create hierarchical view graphs in graphviz?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hierarchy, graphviz

I'm using graphviz to make images from .dot files in ubuntu using this command:

```
sfdp -x -Goverlap=scale -Tpng file.dot > file.png
```

However the result looks the images on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417411/laying-out-a-large-graph-with-graphviz) where its circular and compact. Is there a way to make it look hierarchical like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Pyramid_to_linear_hierarchy.png)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to draw directed graphs as hierarchies, you may use `[dot][1]` to layout your graph instead of `sfdp`:

```
dot -Tpng file.dot -o file.png
```

Your graph should be *acyclic*. If it is not, you may have to [reverse the direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18878093/63733) (and add `dir=back`) of an edge or two in order to get the desired results.